# 2sxc Getting Items Via REST API. Using Pipeline Query with Parameters

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke

Following on from an [issue I submitted](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1478) - Which now works great on DNN 9.2...

I was hoping to be able to expand on this to create an API which could be passed parameters to filter the data.

I currently have a DNN set-up using a few 2sxc instances which use a Visual Pipeline query to pull data through to certain pages.

For example I have a query which looks for data-items in a certain continent:

[image: Diagram]

This works great on the actual site, as the data is filtered from the tab / page name.

I am in the process of trying to build a prototype ReactJs app, using 2sxc as a data source.

Now that the previously mentioned bug has been fixed I can do a REST "GET" request to a url such as:

http://10.51.51.91/api/2sxc/app/My-App/query/My-Custom-Query

And this will return all the items.

My question is:
**Is it possible to perform a filter on a Visual Query / Pipeline via REST API?**

I would expect / hope that there would be a way to do something like this:

http://10.51.51.91/api/2sxc/app/My-App/query/My-Custom-Query?Continent=Europe

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more searching I managed to get an answer to this...

I read the [Wiki - Http WebAPI and REST API](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/webapi) again and found this:

> This kind of a call [root-path]/app/auto/query/BlogPostsByAuthor?Author=Daniel%20Mettler
>   ...would run the pre-defined query and return the Blog Posts of this author

I downloaded the [Blog App](https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/dnn-blog-app-for-dnn-dotnetnuke) it refers to and took a look at it's Visual Queries / Pipelines - It uses the "QueryString" format to filter [image: diagram]

Altering this to be used in my app allows me to use a URL like this:

http://10.51.51.91/api/2sxc/app/My-App/query/Filter-by-Continent?Continent=Asia

In summary:

**My mistake was using the "Tabname" parameter - Rather than a "QueryString"**

Comment: Glad you could fix it!